# completion handler not getting called

Tags: ios, urlsession

I learned quite a comprehensive approach from this [site](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-make-post-get-update-and-delete-requests-with-urlsession-using-swift/). I customized it a bit to include an escaping closure, but its not getting called and I'm not receiving any response at the caller level.

I put break points within all guards to see if its exiting at some level, but so far no clue.

```
func getUsers(_ completion: @escaping (String?, NSException?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/employees") else {
        completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "Error validating URL.", userInfo: nil))
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("1")
            completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: error?.localizedDescription, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("2")
            completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "Did not receive data.", userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("3")
            completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "HTTP request failed.", userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "Cannot convert data to JSON object.", userInfo: nil))
                return
            }
            guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data.", userInfo: nil))
                return
            }
            guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "Could print JSON in String.", userInfo: nil))
                return
            }
            
            print(prettyPrintedJson)
            completion("done", nil)
            
        } catch {
            completion(nil, NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "Error"), reason: "Trying to convert JSON data to string.", userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
    }.resume()
}
```

Usage

```
func testGetUsers() {
    userData.getUsers {
        print($0 ?? "result is nil")
        print($1?.name ?? "error is nil")
    }
}
```

Info.plist setting

[image]

Comment: Are you testing in a real iOS project? This isn’t going to work in a playground.

Comment: yes in iOS project and the caller is at the Unit Test

Comment: oh, do i need to wait on something within unit test?

Comment: Also http calls are illegal; you must use https or configure an exception in your Info.plist.

Comment: Certainly, you have to use an expectation. Your code is asynchronous. The test is ending before the networking even starts.

Comment: yes, matt, you are right. how do I wait? also I'm adding function signature around my Usage

Comment: Well in real life you should not do actual networking in a unit test. You should mock the server. But either way, it’s asynchronous and you need an expectation. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations

Comment: `configure an exception in your Info.plist`, please see the screenshot under plist, is this correct?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501012/is-it-safe-to-add-localhost-to-app-transport-security-ats-nsexceptiondomains/40047949#40047949 but I am having some trouble imagining how an iPhone can have a localhost.

Comment: I can find my machine's ip and replace the URL, will that work?

Comment: Matt I appreciate your lead on the Info.plist, that was very helpful. I'm able to call `http` on localhost from the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test, you would use an expectation to wait for the closure to be called, e.g.

```
func testGetUsers() {
    let e = expectation(description: "testGetUsers")

    userData.getUsers {
        print($0 ?? "result is nil")
        print($1?.name ?? "error is nil")
        e.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 10)
}
```

---

In most circles, network requests are not considered unit tests. Often we would “mock” the network responses and just test our app’s ability to handle various types of responses. The goal of unit tests is not to test the integration with the back end, but rather to test how it would handle various theoretical responses.

Comment: thanks Rob, this totally slipped my mind that test function has to outlive the network call.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is there a link where I can find more information on how to mock the network. I'm relatively new coming from java background and having a bit hard time when i tried to lookup mocking