# React native Axios post request works in iOS simulator but not physical phone

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

Currently adding a signUp request in the client

```
  const { email, password } = params;
  console.log(params);
  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register', { email: email, password: password });
```

Which works in simulator but not the iPhone. Any reason that might be? The request also works on postman

Comment: How are you running the Web server on the actual iPhone?

Comment: You can try to enable NSAllowsLocalNetworking in your Infoplist file
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40047949/7956161

Comment: Is the phone connected to the same network that the webserver is running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either configure your web-server to run on an IP that is accessible within the network or you could use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your web-server to the internet (though that's creating a security risk).

You'll also need to make sure that you're not using `localhost` as the API base URL otherwise your phone is going to try and send the request to itself and fail.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! That worked for me